# How to (quickly) prove that $24p+17$ is not a square number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Computer says $24p+17$ is not square number for $p<10^7$ so I guess it's not. I know that squares of odd numbers are all $8p+1$ but $24p+17$ passes the test

And how to solve problems like this in general? Thx in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The number is $2 \pmod 3$. No such number is perfect square.

If you are not familiar with the modular notation, any perfect square is either of the form $3k$ or $3k+1$. Your number is $3k+2$.

Comment: Didn't know that before... thanks!

Comment: @AlexSu If $p$ is a odd prime, then there are exactly $\lfloor \frac{p-1}{2} \rfloor$ values not taken by $x^2 \pmod{p}$. Thus it is worth checking what happens mod $p$.... Also, note that I picked $3$ because it is a divisor of $24$...

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the equation modulo three. Since 3 divides 24 and since $17 = 5\times 3 + 2$ we see that $24p+17 \equiv 2\bmod 3$ for all $p$. Now notice that $0^2 = 0 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$, $1^2 =1 \equiv \bmod 3$ and $2^2 = 4 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$. So no square number is congruent to 2 modulo 3, meaning $24p+17$ is not square.

In general, I looked at the factors of 24. They are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12 and 24. The aim now is to reduce $24p+17$ modulo one of these factors. You then need to find a factor that when you reduce 17 modulo that factor, you get a number which is not given by squaring any of the members of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

For example, let's try $n=6$. $24p+17 \equiv 5 \bmod 6$. Next $0^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 6$, $1^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, $2^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 6$, $3^2 \equiv 3 \bmod 6$, $4^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 6$ and $5^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 6$. Again, no square is congruent to 5 modulo 6, while $24p+17$ *is* congruent to 5 modulo 6. Again, this proves that $24p+17$ is not a square.

Comment: thx for the detail!

Comment: @AlexSu No problem. I've added details about how to do this generally.

Comment: great! So in some sense 24 is a good number for this sort of problem, as 24 has more factors than its neighbors

Comment: @AlexSu That's an interesting question. I think it says that 24 gives a greater chance of this type of modulo proof working. That might have implications in itself. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

$24$ is the largest number $m$ with the property that $x^2=1$ mod $m$ for all $x$ coprime to $m$.

This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem. It implies that among the residue classes coprime to $24$, only the numbers of the form $24p+1$ contains perfect squares.

Comment: ,that's what I've proved, right?

Comment: curious property..

Comment: @bhattacharjee, You proved that $24$ has the property that $x^2=1$ mod $24$, yes. I was just noting that it's the largest such number.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to “Prove that in Base 24, no square number ends in the digit H (i.e., seventeen).”

Reading down the diagonal of the quadrovigesimal [multiplication table](http://www.dozenal.org/articles/DSA-Mult.pdf) gives the square numbers as: 1, 4, 9, G, 11, 1C, 21, 2G, 39, 44, 51, 60, 71, 84, 99, AG, C1, DC, F1, GG, I9,
 K4, M1, 100.

Thus, in quadrovigesimal, all square numbers end in one of the digits {0, 1, 4, 9, C, G}, which does not include H.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the "general" way to solve such problems without fail. And the link you give is interesting

Answer (score 1):

Any number not divisible by $6,$ can be expressed as $6p\pm1, 6p\pm 2,6p\pm 3$ where $p$ is any integer

If $p$ is an odd natural number, as $24p+17$ is odd and is not divisible by $3,$ its square root(if any) must of the form $6p\pm1$  as prime $q$ divides integer $n\iff q$ divides $n^2$

$$\text{Now, }(6p\pm1)^2=36p^2\pm12p+1=24p^2+24\frac{p(p\pm1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod {24}$$

Also (it's not required here), 
$$(6p\pm2)^2=36p^2\pm24p+4=12p^2\pm24p+4=12(p^2-1)\pm24p+16\equiv16\pmod {24}\text{ as } 2  (\text{ in fact } 8 )\text{ divides } (p^2-1) \text{ for odd  }p$$

$$(6p\pm3)^2=36p^2\pm36p+9=72\frac{p(p\pm1)}2+9\equiv9\pmod {24}$$

Comment: this takes some math insight I guess... 6 must be important in number theory

Comment: @AlexSu, please have  a look into the edited answer

Comment: thanks, I wouldn't have realized that classifying numbers by modulo 6 is sufficient for this problem. I tried modulo 3 and it didn't work so I thought I had to use modulo 24 xD

Comment: @AlexSu, as N.S. has shown, classifying by modulo $3,$ is sufficient, but this pattern is legitimate and has come handy in many cases for me.

Comment: yup, my original attempt was to break a number downto the form of 3p+1, take the square, and consequently found nothing quite useful...to be honest I'm quite ignorant of number theory: I know the basic concepts and rules of modular arithmetic that I can understand your answer, but not sufficient to prove anything on my own